# What is the Android Studio's Default Qualifier for Layout Resource Directory?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Creating a project in Android Studio with an Empty Activity would produce a project with an existing layout resource directory.

If I create a project without an activity and decide to add an activity later, I'll need to create a layout resource directory to put the layout file in there. Before it's created it needs a qualifier.

Is Android studio using any default qualifiers when creating an xml layout for the Empty Activity project?

In the image below you can see the window where IDE is asking for the qualifier.

[image]

Comment: You mean the name of the layout's directory?

Comment: No, not the name of the directory; But the **Qualifier** for the layout's directory before it's created. This is the [image](https://i.imgur.com/xDL9isz.png) of Android Studio asking for a Qualifier.

Comment: You don't require XML layouts for activities. For example, research the Anko library

Answer (score 0):

As per investigation, I found out the **Layout** Resource directory I'm talking about is just a normal directory like a folder added to a project. The layout XMLs in projects created with an empty activity would be put in a normal directory without qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

In case you created a new Blank Activity, and you want to add new layouts for activities with a default qualifier you have two options

### Manualy create directory

You can just create a directory in your project:

```
app/src/main/res/layout
```

About the Android project structure:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/#ProjectView

Resource types specificly:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourceTypes

### New Resource Directory Wizard

You can also do it in the Android Studio, the way you posted in the question. 
Select: **File -> New -> Android resource directory**.

I am pasting a screenshot so you can see my Android resource directory wizard where I am allowed to create default resource directory. See I do not need to explicitly to select any qualifier, I don't know why is IDE asking you to provide one. Maybe its because we are using different version of Android Studio.

[image]